# Unable to change view on sidebar button click - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap, sidebar

I'm pretty new to react. It's been only a few days since I started react.
I have a question regarding routing. I'm trying to change the main content on the sidebar button click. I think I'm doing something wrong with linking pages right.

In below `Sidebar.js` class, I am linking the dashboard page on button click with `to="/admin/dashboard"`

Below is the `Sidebar.js` class

```dart
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Sidebar = () => {
  return (
    <nav className="sb-sidenav accordion sb-sidenav-dark" id="sidenavAccordion">
      <div className="sb-sidenav-menu">
        <div className="nav">
          <div className="sb-sidenav-menu-heading">Core</div>
          <Link className="nav-link" to="/admin/dashboard">  // <<<--- Here I'm linking button
            <div className="sb-nav-link-icon">
              <i className="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
            </div>
            Dashboard
          </Link>
           ......... Similar type of code .......
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="sb-sidenav-footer">
        <div className="small">Logged in as:</div>
        Ecommerce React Laravel admin
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};
export default Sidebar;
```

Below is `App.js`

```dart
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import MasterLayout from "./layouts/admin/MasterLayout";
import Home from "./components/frontend/Home";


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route
            path="/admin/*"
            name="Admin"
            element={<MasterLayout />}
          />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Below is the `MasterLayout.js`

```dart
import React from "react";
import { Navigate, Route, Routes, Router } from "react-router-dom";
import "../../assets/admin/css/styles.css";
import "../../assets/admin/js/scripts";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import routes from "../../routes/routes";
import Dashboard from "../../components/admin/Dashboard";

const MasterLayout = () => {
  return (
    <div className="sb-nav-fixed">
      <Navbar />
      <div id="layoutSidenav">
        <div id="layoutSidenav_nav">
          <Sidebar />
        </div>
        <div id="layoutSidenav_content">
          <main>
            <Routes>
              { routes.map((route, idx) => {
              return (
                route.element && ( 
                  <Route
                    key={idx}
                    path={route.path}
                    name={route.name}
                    element={route.element}
                    />
                 )
               );
            })}
            </Routes>
          </main>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default MasterLayout;
```

Below is the `routes.js` class

```dart
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/admin/dashboard",
    name: "Dashboard",
    element: <Dashboard />,
  },
  {
    path: "/admin/profile",
    name: "Profile",
    element: <Profile />,
  },
  { path: "/", name: "Admin", element: <Dashboard /> },
];
```

Below is `dashboard.js`

```dart
import React from "react";

function Dashboard() {
  return <h1>I'm Dashboard</h1>;
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Below is the file directory

[image]

This link is changing as desired. Browser URL look as expected when clicking the link

[image]

Comment: have you tried removing the `route.element &&` from the map? I don't think you need that at all

Answer (score 0):

The `element` prop takes a `ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX. Instead of passing a reference to a React component pass it as JSX. The routes should also be relative from the `/"admin/*"` path rendered in `App`.

```
const routes = [
  { path: "/", name: "Admin", element: <Dashboard /> },
  {
    path: "dashboard",
    name: "Dashboard",
    element: <Dashboard />,
  },
  {
    path: "profile",
    name: "Profile",
    element: <Profile />,
  },
];
```

[image: Edit unable-to-change-view-on-sidebar-button-click-react]

Comment: I updated as you said but still same issue

Comment: @FaizanKamal Using relative paths appears to work. I updated my answer and included a running codesandbox demo.